# Adding Kendo UI to existing ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I'm just getting my feet wet with ASP.NET MVC 5 and Kendo. Using the existing MS tutorials, I've created an ASP.NET project that does roughly what I want (some data input from various users). Now I'm trying to add Kendo UI to the project, but I'm not sure how to convert the existing Razor cshtml to use Kendo correctly.

For example, I have:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.someDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})
```

I tried changing it to:

```
@Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor( model => model.someDate).Name( "someDate" ).HtmlAttributes( new { style = "width:100%" } )
```

This works, in that I see the Kendo UI date picker. But if I use it to choose a date and save the data, I get this exception:

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The conversion
>   of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an
>   out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

I'd thought I could just drop in the Kendo controls, but apparently not. Is it possible to get this to work just like the original Html.EditorFor code? If so, how?

Comment: Check in the POST method what the value of `someDate` is. I assume binding is failing and its `1/1/0001`?

Comment: Hi Stephen. Thanks! I found the problem. I had a typo in the Name() part, so it wasn't storing the value back into the correct field.

Comment: Do not use `.Name()`. Inspect the html your generating - the `name` attribute is added automatically (don't try and override it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `.Name( "someDate" )`. So your code will be:

```
@Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor( model => model.someDate).HtmlAttributes( new { style = "width:100%" } )
```

Comment: Thanks, Hadee!  That worked, and seems like a much cleaner way to do it. I'm not sure now how the .Name() got added;  just glad things work now.